# DataTables JQuery não renderiza botão em coluna no Codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando colocar botões de ação na minha tabela através do plugin datatTable.

***Meu código Javascript***

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "contentType": "application/json",
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/usuario/listar"                           
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": -1,
            "data": null
            }
        }]
    });


});
```

***e meu Controller no Codeigniter***

```
<?php


class Usuario extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('UsuarioModel');
    }



    public function listar(){
        $data = $this->UsuarioModel->all()->result();
        $row = [];
        foreach($data as $dados){
            $row[] = array($dados->nome, $dados->endereco);

        }
        $d['data'] = $row;
        echo json_encode($d);
    }



}
```

*A ideia é que pelo DataTable ele criar botões de ação com "editar", "remover", "visualizar" com o id no botão da minha resposta json.*

Comment: Pelo código apresentado vc não está criando os botoes, para o Datatables.
Você pode fazer essa criação pelo PHP mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitua essa parte do seu código:

```
            $row[] = array($dados->nome, $dados->endereco);
```

por essa:

```
           $row[] = $dados->nome;
           $row[] =  $dados->endereco;
           $row[] = "<a href='" . base_url() . "controle/editar/" . $dados->id . "'class='btn btn-primary' >Editar</a>";
```

Comment: Explique o seu código, as vezes a pessoa não entendeu, não sabe onde deve colocar, não conhece alguma função, etc.

Comment: já fiz a alteração